# Making A Report with this Diagram

Tags: reporting, lookup, object

[image]

Hi everyone. I have 5 objects (**Account,B,C,D,E**) and the **lookup** relationships are shown in the picture. I can create a **summary report** with objects (Accounts,B,C) with no problem as I can find the report type in **Other Reports** -> **Account with B with C**.

My problem is now I need the total of **Amount** field from **Object C** by using **Object E** (Name) as a means of grouping but I also need them to be grouped by **Account**(Name) at the same time. The final report wil be shown per Account and will contain the total Amount from Object C per grouping with Object E.

Ex.
Sample Org (Account)

Object E --- Object C (sum of Amount)

Type 1   ------ $100

Type 2   ------ $200

Type 3   ------ $150

Is it possible to make such report? If so, can anyone please enlighten me?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I had, I did the following:

1. I made 2 fields in Object C: 1 **lookup** to Object E, 1 text **formula** to get the Name of the lookup (I needed this for the grouping later in the reports)
2. I made a trigger that auto-fills the **lookup** (made a step 1) every time I lookup object C with D.
3. I created a summary report using 3 Objects (Account,B,C) and I grouped them by C (text **formula** I made) and Account.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to create a Custom Report Type that will make this possible, or create a number of formula fields on the C object that reference the parent objects.

With both Custom Report Types and formula fields, you can include fields from parent (and grand-parent) objects, and then you can use those fields as though they exist on the child object.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Nick. I tried making a custom report type but only allows up to four objects (mine has five) and the lookup flow must be one way ( mine has 2 lookup flows (Unit holdings to account, Unit holdings to E).

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you can just make it on the C object and include fields from the other 4 objects via the parent relationships.